# Getting Destroyed on SEO

Tags: seo, google, search-engines

So I've launched a website and I'm working on SEO. Recently, many of my #1 result pages have completely evaporated from google. I am guessing Google is spam-flagging my site, and I have no idea what to do. Every page has at least a paragraph of unique content, my site has been backlinked from media articles (Google doesn't seem to think I have any backlinks) and I've been including tags in the URL (redirecting old links with a 301).

My pages are very template-generic, yet that's just because of the design. Each page is indeed unique.

Comment: Define "[completely evaporated](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Atldrlegal.com)." (Webmaster Tools will tell you exactly how many pages are indexed; this is just a quick external cheat.)

Answer (score 3):

check the webmaster tool > indexed page details  and check how many pages indexed

1. also try to Fetch As Googlebot to check that it is accessible to google.

and then make sure that there is a good, clear, text-based link to it from the home page or other suitable page.  You want to make sure that it is not accidentally "orphaned" and the home page is recrawled most often.

In addition, **check that there is nothing on that page which would be seen negatively by search engines (eg hidden text, spam, linking to bad neighborhoods, etc).**

if it is temp issue you can see pages re index in few days . else try to resubmit the sitemap

Comment: @Kevin - [Google] Webmaster Tools _is_ Google. If you are referring to a Google search such as link:example.com - this is never particularly accurate and is also only showing links to a particular URL.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried searching other pages besides page one on Google search results. Also try site:your-domain-name.com in Google search, sometimes your site is listed on Google, but not on the first page.